# Trying to modify column type but get error

Tags: postgresql

I'm running this command

```
alter table client_details alter column name type character varying(120);
```

but then get the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "view" at character 7
LINE 1: alter view v1 alter column name type character varying(120);
```

I've noticed that a view exists thats causing the problem, how can I alter the type in the vieww, or solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately PostgreSQL is very strict about this.

You need to drop the view that references that table, then alter the column type and then recreate the view.